# Java Cannot replace a string followed by \n

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I'm a college student working on a semester long project and I have hit a wall with my program.  Before I go any further, do know that I looked through the similar threads on stack overflow and none of them seem to match my situation.

I have a string input generated from a pdf that contains abundant data from a table.  Problem is, some of the table entries for the department column go from 1 row to 2 due to the formatting and I am unable to address it.  For example,

PS 253 (handled fine by my algorithm)

MA

243HON (breaks everything)

I need to ultimately be able to put them on the same row and remove the " \n" after MA to send it along to the rest of the program.  I attempted checking for \n one or two index places after the department code (MA) and changing the index from which I get 243HON, which did not work.

I have also tried String = string.replaceAll("MA \n", "MA ") as seen in the code.  Removing the space between MA and \n does nothing.  Here is the relevant part of my code.  Thank you!

```
public static String[] departments = {"\nAS","\nSF","\nAE","\nAF","\nAT","\nLAR","\nAMS","\nBIO","\nBA","\nCHM","\nLCH","\nCIV","\nCSO",
        "\nCOM","\nCEC","\nCS","\nCYB","\nEC","\nEE","\nEGR","\nEP","\nES","\nFA","\nGCS","\nHS","\nHON","\nHF","\nHU","\nMA","\nME","\nWX",
        "\nMSL","\nNSC","\nPE","\nPS","\nPSY","\nSIM","\nSS","\nSE","\nSP","\nSYS","\nUNIV","\nUA"};

public static String[] departmentsFix = {"\nAS \n","\nSF \n","\nAE \n","\nAF \n","\nAT \n","\nLAR \n","\nAMS \n","\nBIO \n","\nBA \n","\nCHM \n","\nLCH \n","\nCIV \n","\nCSO \n",
        "\nCOM \n","\nCEC \n","\nCS \n","\nCYB \n","\nEC \n","\nEE \n","\nEGR \n","\nEP \n","\nES \n","\nFA \n","\nGCS \n","\nHS \n","\nHON \n","\nHF \n","\nHU \n","\nMA  \n","\nME \n","\nWX \n",
        "\nMSL \n","\nNSC \n","\nPE \n","\nPS \n","\nPSY \n","\nSIM \n","\nSS \n","\nSE \n","\nSP \n","\nSYS \n","\nUNIV \n","\nUA \n"};


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Loader loader = new Loader();
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\EclipseWorkspace\\SE 300\\ER_SCHED_PRT.pdf");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
        loader.content = s.getText(document);

        String[] splitString = loader.content.split("Instructor", 2);

        loader.content = splitString[1];

        int index = 0;
        for (String y : departmentsFix) {
            //find any departments with a \n after them and replace it with a space
            loader.content = loader.content.replaceAll(y, departments[index] + " ");
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regular expressions (see chandras answer) - `replace` uses normal texts (but also replaces all occurrences)...

Comment: I also suggest using only one index to access both arrays in above loop, not mixing for-each and extra index; even better, use a Map or some structure to avoid having 2 arrays  that can be messed up (if must be, a 2D array).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just fixed it.  Through the find function, I had discovered that instead of \nMA \n, the format was \nMA \r\n.  Changing that largely fixed the problem with a minor irrelevant bug which can be compensated for using an extra space.  Thank you for your help nonetheless.